# Video.js controls come back on pause even though disabled

Tags: video.js

The subject pretty much says it all.  I have a Video.js instance with controls turned off (aka no "controls" in the markup).  It works brilliantly, but when I pause the video (using my external custom button and myPlayer.pause() the controls on the video fade back in.  When I hit play, they fade out again.

This definitely doesn't seem like the way it should work.  Does anyone know if this is a bug, or I'm just missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctangney's answer only works when using the uncompressed (dev) version of videojs, since once compressed the lockShowing method is renamed (so is player() for that matter). Hopefully his merge request for [issue 556](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/556) will be accepted soon.

When lockShowing is called on pause() it adds the class `vjs-lock-showing` to the controls element, which has the css: `display: block !important`. This is causing the inline style of `display:none`, added by the disable() method, to be trumped. Here is work around which addresses the CSS specificity problem, and works with the compressed and uncompressed videojs:

```
var v = videojs("video", {});
if(!v.controls()) {
  v.controlBar.el().className = v.controlBar.el().className + ' vjs-controls-disabled';
}
```

Then add to the bottom of the css file(s):

```
.vjs-controls-disabled {display: none !important;}
```

(Or you could just remove the `!important` from `.vjs-lock-showing`)

Comment: This worked like a charm, thank you!   Like you said, hopefully the fix will be merged sometime in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [confirmed bug](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/556). I see a proposed fix there, but it's still an open pull request at the moment. In the meantime you can fix this by just overwriting the ControlBar's lockShowing method.

```
var vid = videojs("video", {});

if (!vid.player().controls()) {
  vid.controlBar.lockShowing = function(){};
}
```

... since (currently) the controlbar attaches a listener to 'pause' events and calls lockShowing().